# How can I disable an Apple laptop's touchpad button (physical click)?

Tags: trackpad

I really want to find a way to disable the Apple touchpad physical tap button. My wife does not make use of the software tap functionality that I enabled. She sits next to me every night clicking away. This is very annoying when it goes on for several hours.

There has to be a way to catch / trap the input from the device.

Comment: Buy her an iPad?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the question. Your wife does not want to use the 'tap'. So that leaves here with the physical click. Now you want to disable the physical click? What do you mean by 'trap the input'? Don't you want to disable the click noise?

Comment: I think @CarpeNoctem wants physical clicks to do nothing, so his wife, in order to click, should just tap.

Comment: I myself find the 'tap' feature rather annoying due to all the accidental clicks. Rather than forcing your wife to use the 'tap' against her will, try to [manually tweak her MBP](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IuYO0I-DY84). There is not only a chance to reduce the noise, but also that your wife will be madly impressed with your 'geekiness' and bakes you an awesome cake thereafter. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can configure it using [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/). But I'd advice against pissing your wife off.

There's always option of buying an iPad.

Comment: I'll give this a shot today. Good advice all around, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The trackpad click is a hardware thing: it's not added in software, so it cannot be trapped or otherwise blocked. (And, yes, they are awfully loud.) The only way to do what you want would be to disassemble the laptop and try to add some muffling around the trackpad mechanism.

Personally, I find tap-to-click infuriating and unusable, so I, too, would use the physical (clicky) buttons, no matter how loud they are.